# How do I set the value of a date and time field with Behat?

Tags: testing

I am trying to test my site with Behat.

On my entity edit form, I have a **Datetime** field that uses the **Date and time** widget.  I want to use the **Date and time** widget because I need to set the time in increments of seconds, which I cannot do with the **Select list** widget.

I want to set the value of this field with a step like this:

```
And I assign the date "yesterday" with timezone "Asia/Tokyo" for "edit-field-datetime-MYFIELD-0-value"
```

To do so, in `FeatureContext.php`, I wrote the following code.

```
  /**
   * @Then I assign the date :date with timezone :timezone for :field
   *
   * Assign the specified date to the element with the given CSS.
   */
  public function assertEnterDateForField($field, $timezone, $date_string) {
    $date_field = $field . '-date';
    $time_field = $field . '-time';
    // Drupal stores timezones as UTC so we need the base time in UTC.
    $datetime = new DateTime($date_string, timezone_open('UTC'));
    // We need to convert the UTC time to the user's timezone.
    // This is because when saving the entity,
    // Drupal will convert the value to UTC.
    $datetime->setTimezone(timezone_open($timezone));
    $date_output_string = $datetime->format('mdY');
    $time_output_string = $datetime->format('hisA');
    $datetime_debug_string = $datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO');
    $this->fillfield($time_field, $time_output_string);
    $this->fillField($date_field, $date_output_string);
    echo "Datetime $datetime_debug_string
    Field set to
    date: $date_output_string
    time: $time_output_string";
  }
```

On my local environment (lando, running the [Standalone Chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/) container), this code works as expected; the date/time is set correctly for the field.

However, on my test server (Pantheon/CircleCI, running the [Behat Chrome Extension](https://packagist.org/packages/dmore/behat-chrome-extension), it doesn't work.  The debug information is correct; for example:

```
  │ Datetime 2020-08-13T09:00:00+0900
  │     Field set to
  │     date: 08132020
  │     time: 090000AM
```

However, the date/time is not actually filled in, so when the entity is saved, the date/time has not been updated.

How can I set the value of a field that uses the **Date and time** widget with Behat/Mink/Drupal Extension?

Answer (score 1):

```
When I fill in the date field "Publish on" with "+1 second"
```

I get it to work with these updates.

```
  /**
   * @Then I fill in the date field :field with :date
   *
   * Assign the specified date to the element.
   */
  public function iFillDateField($field, $date): void {
    $field_label = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('xpath', "//*[text() = '$field']");
    if ($field_label == NULL | !$field_label->hasClass('form-item__label')) {
      throw new ExpectationException('Could not find date field with label: ' . $field, $this->getSession());
    }

    $datetime = new \DateTime($date, \timezone_open('UTC'));
    $datetime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(\date_default_timezone_get()));

    $date_input = $field_label->getParent()->find('xpath', "//input[@type='date']");
    $date_output_string = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->fillField($date_input->getAttribute('id'), $date_output_string);

    $time_input = $field_label->getParent()->find('xpath', "//input[@type='time']");
    if ($time_input) {
      $time_output_string = $datetime->format('H:i:s');
      $this->getSession()->getPage()->fillField($time_input->getAttribute('id'), $time_output_string);
    }
  }
```

The key to get it work is to set the right formats for date (Y-m-d) and time (H:i:s).

This step will accept the field label instead of the field id.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The browser reports "Please enter a valid value. The field is incomplete or has an invalid date" specifically over the time element. I've tried `H:i:s` or `H:i:s A` or 'h:i:s A` to no avail. The element shows everything but the AM/PM designation so I know something is off in chrome/chromium.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't been able to find a way to do this, so for now, I rewrote my CI configuration so that I can use Standalone Chrome with Pantheon/CircleCI instead of the Behat Chrome Extension.